# For finitely generated free abelian groups $A,B$ if there is an onto homomorphism $A \to B$, then $\operatorname{rank}(A) \geq \operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$For two finitely generated, free abelian groups $A,B$ prove that if there is an onto homomorphism $A \rightarrow B$, then $\rank(A) \geq \rank(B)$

Assume that $\rank(A) < \rank(B)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rank(A) = n$ and $\rank(B) = m$ s.t. $m \gt n$.

Let's take a generating set of $B$ with $m$ elements. From the fact that we have an onto homomorphism, each $b_m$ can be written as the image of a linear generating set of $A$ (such a set has $n$ elements). Therefore:

$$\forall 1 \leq \ell \leq n:\
b_\ell = f\left(\sum \alpha_i a_i\right) = \sum f(\alpha_ia_i) = \sum f(\alpha_i) f(a_i) = \sum \beta_i f(a_i)$$

Therefore every set of $m$ linearly independent elements in $B$ can be written as a linear sum of $n$ elements, namely $f(a_i)$, which is in contradiction to the fact that $m > n$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't really a proof by contradiction: you showed the image of a basis of $A$ is a generating set for $B$. The conclusion follows immediately.

Comment: Alright thanks for this!

Comment: I must say many so-called proofs by contradiction are not really by contradiction (mostly they're proofs by contraposition), and I prefer to avoid them if possible, as they're less convincing for beginners.